# angular 2 loads component too early

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I have an angular 2 and it's built somewhat in the following way

app.component - has several routes - one of them is some-data-component, which isn't the default route shown first.

some-data-component - has a list, where you can select an item - when it is selected I want to display the selected item in a data-details-component.

the thing is, data-detail-component is being loaded at the start of the app - and I am getting the following error from it's html

> Cannot read property 'students' of undefined

this makes sense, because I haven't chosen an item yet, so it should be undefined

is there a way for me to build my app so it won't build those other components unless they are shown?

this is my code:

app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import { Dashboard } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {SomeDataComponent} from './some-data-component/some-data-component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/components/app.component.html'
  , directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] 
})
@Routes([
        { path: '/somedata', component: SomeDataComponent},
        { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard }
])
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    mobileView: number = 992;
    toggle: boolean = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.attachEvents();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
}
```

some-data-component

```
import {SomeDataListView} from '../some-data-list-view/some-data-list-view';
import {DataDetailComponent} from '../data-detail/data-detail.component';

import {SomeService} from '../../services/some_service';    

@Component({
    selector: 'some-data-component',
    providers: [SomeService],
    templateUrl: 'app/components/some-data/some-data.html',
    directives: [SomeDataListView, DataDetailComponent]
})
export class RoutesComponent {
    data;
    selectedData;

    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
        this.data=[]
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data= this.SomeService.all();
    }

    selectedRouteChanged(route) {
        this.selectedRoute = route;
    }
}
```

some-data.html

```html
<rd-widget>
    <rd-widget-body classes="medium no-padding">
        <div>
            <img src="{{route.imgSrc}}" />
            <label>Neighborhood: {{route.name}}</label>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                            <th>Neighborhood</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let student of route.students" (click)="setSelected(route)">
                            <td>{{student.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{student.neighborhood}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="{{route.tooltipcls}}">
                                    <i class="fa {{route.icon}}"></i>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </rd-widget-body>
</rd-widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Elvis operator:

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of route?.students" ...
```

Comment: but, still, isn't it bad that it preloads a component that it shouldn't? it will probably solve the error thrown, but this seems like a  kind of a workaround..

Comment: I don't want it to show the component when it's null, 
I don't want it to load until it needs to be shown